# Setting Wallpaper of Firebase Storage Image inside an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, firebase-storage, freeze, android-wallpaper

I'm having a little trouble with setting my device wallpaper while having my Firebase Storage code inside and AsyncTask.

**Firstly**, is it proper to have this code contained in an AsyncTask at all?

**Secondly**, the wallpaper is successfully downloaded and set, but for some reason the AsyncTask isn't waiting for that to complete before dismissing the ProgressDialog and showing a Toast telling me that the wallpaper has been set successfully. What might be going wrong here?

**Thirdly**, even though the code is within doInBackground() of the AsyncTask, it doesn't seem like it's actually running separate from the main thread, because my app completely freezes while the code is being run (and eventually unfreezes when it's finished).

Any insight for me? I'm learning as I go and am pretty confused.

Here's the code for reference below.

```
private class wallpaperTaskHome extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(PhotoDetailsActivity.this);
```

**onPreExecute()**

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        // Progress dialog to show user that the app is working...
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.wallpaper_please_wait));
        dialog.show();
    }
```

**doInBackground()**

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Get Intent data from intent passed from Photos.java class.
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int position = intent.getExtras().getInt("Image int");

        final StorageReference fullSizeImagesStoragePath = mStorageRef.child("images_full_size/" + position + ".jpg");
        fullSizeImagesStoragePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                // Retrieve a WallpaperManager
                final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                        .getInstance(PhotoDetailsActivity.this);

                Glide
                        .with(PhotoDetailsActivity.this)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .load(uri)
                        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                                try {
                                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(resource, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
```

**onPostExecute()**

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        // Show a Toast message on successful wallpaper change
        showToastWallpaperApplied();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you could provide me with!

**EDIT:** I've changed my `doInBackground()` method to look like below, which essentially does the same thing, but now at least it's trying to call the whole code asynchronously because it gives me the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread`

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
            .getInstance(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int position = intent.getExtras().getInt("Image int");

    final StorageReference fullSizeImagesStoragePath = mStorageRef.child("images_full_size/" + position + ".jpg");
    GlideApp.with(PhotoDetailsActivity.this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(fullSizeImagesStoragePath)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    try {
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(resource, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            });
```

It points to `.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>()` as being the method that wants to run only on the main thread. Help?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is glide internally will call onSuccess on UI thread,  then your task of setting wallpaper still runs on ui thread, even you wrap it in the async task. I suggest you checking the implementation of the related methods of glide.

Edit:
If that the case, then you will need to wrap your set wallpaper task into an async task too, which will be very tedious to be implement. My suggestion is to use Rxjava to chain these tasks together, which imo will be a better approach.

Edit:
Took a look at the docs, 
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Loading-and-Caching-on-Background-Threads
it said

> If you actually want to interact with a decoded image on a background
>   thread, instead of using downloadOnly you can use the version of
>   into() that returns a FutureTarget

So you can try loading your image synchronously on a background thread(by async task) to avoid blocking ui, but make sure to call it with application context to avoid memory leaks.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = Glide.with(applicationContext)
    .load(yourUrl)
    .asBitmap()
    .centerCrop()
    .into(500, 500)
    .get()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Are there any examples of code that perform something like these functions that you could reference me to (whether the Rxjava method, or otherwise)? I'm not entirely sure where I should go to get started on how to implement these methods for my specific needs.

Comment: Every time I try to call `.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>()` inside an Async method, I get the error: `IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread`. Is there not another way I could be doing this? Obviously putting this function in a non-Async environment causes the app to freeze as usual, since it's being called on the main thread... What should I do?

Comment: I have edited the answer, you may try with this approach